# wordpress images wont display

Tags: wordpress, image

I have problem with wordpress images.

It's embarassing but I cant get images to display on my wordpress site.
I used media library url for the img src tags, Links work well on pc as you enter them in adress bar but not on the website.

Any suggestions more than welcome.Here's my website link [http://produkcja.adlike.pl/](http://produkcja.adlike.pl)

Many thanks in advance,
Neko

Answer (score 0):

If you see to the browser console you will see many errors. Almost all of them are because an image was not found in the server, but there are others.

The images not found are because they have bad URL:

```
http://produkcja.adlike.pl/images/index_img05.jpg
```

instead of

```
http://produkcja.adlike.pl/public_html/produkcja/wp-content/themes/Mywordpresstheme/images/index_img05.jpg
```

There is only one that seems to have correct URL and is getting an error: http://produkcja.adlike.pl/public_html/produkcja/wp-content/themes/Mywordpresstheme/images/index_img03.jpg

I think it can be caused by the other errors or because you are implementing a responsive images script, incorrectly (I see you have data-src in your images)

Comment: Ok I've tried http://produkcja.adlike.pl/public_html/produkcja/wp-content/themes/Mywordpresstheme/images/index_img05.jpg and it didnt work.How to implement them correctly?

Comment: I've replaced one div tag with a image tag and broken link appeared. That's another weird thing.I cant see broken link icon for other images,

Comment: I've replaced div tag with image tag and used media library url and it works!

Comment: The div tags with data-src are from the responsive image script, if you remove it will not work for sure.

Comment: Also when I go to http://produkcja.adlike.pl/public_html/produkcja/wp-content/themes/Mywordpresstheme/images/index_slide01.jpg is not appearing the image, it appears the all website...

Comment: I was happy too fast. I've removed data-src divs and replaced url for the media library one but it only worked for 3 images.Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: I've removed all scripts and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in css, when I removed class lazy-image the images appeared.